# Page layout after JSF 2 and IceFaces 3 Migration

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I just finished a migration from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2 and IceFaces 1.8 to Icefaces 3 and I noticed that the page layout is not exactly right.  Is there a way to make the JSF 2 layout render the same as the JSF 1.2 layout?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is way too vague and broad. We have no idea what you mean with "exactly right". Some screenshots along with relevant parts of the generated HTML code may be helpful.